# MySQL SUM () INNER JOIN AND LIMIT using FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql, sum, subquery, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following tables:
Vehicles:

1. VID Primary key
2. Reg_no
3. Date
4. Initial_mileage

Mileage

1. MID primary key
2. Reg_no FOREIGN KEY
3. Date
4. Miles_covered
5. To_service
6. Total

What I want is to sum(Total) for each last row of foreign key in mileage table.

[image]

In this case a query to sum MID 7 and MID 19

What I've tried:

```
    SELECT SUM(Mileage.Total) Totals 
    FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM Mileage 
        INNER JOIN Vehicles on Mileage.Registration_No=Vehicles.Registration_No 
        ORDER BY Mileage.MID DESC Limit 1
    ) SUB 
    ORDER BY Mileage.MID ASC;
```

I receive error 1060

What am I not doing right and how do I do it?

Comment: Please post table data as text, not picture.

Comment: "What I want is to sum(Total) for each last row of foreign key in mileage table..." -- How do you define the **last row**? The date is not good enough since there are duplicate values.

Comment: Also please post error description. No one remember all error codes

Comment: You used the phrase *last row*. The thing is, SQL tables are *unordered sets of rows*. The concepts of first and last don't exist unless you specify them. What do you mean by *last row*? The one with the largest MID primary key? Date? Mileage?  Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter with a subquery, then aggregate. Assuming that `mid` can be used as an ordering column:

```
select sum(m.total) sum_total
from mileage m
where m.mid = (
    select max(m1.mid) from mileage m1 where m1.registration_no = m.registration_no
)
```

This works on all versions of MySQL, and should be an efficient solution, provided that you have an index on `(registration_no, mid)`.

Note that you don't need the `vehicle` table to get the result that you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are finding the "last row" by the greatests `MID` value, then your query could look like:

```
select sum(total) as totals 
from (
  select m.total,
    row_number() over(partition by m.registration_no 
                      order by m.mid desc) as rn
  from mileage m
  join vehicles v on v.registration_no = m.registration_no
) sub
where sub.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep all info from the vehicle table, you can also do this

```
SELECT V.*, COALESCE(SUM(M.Total),0) AS ToTal_Last_Mileage
FROM Vehicles V
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Reg_no, MAX(MID) AS MAxID
    FROM Mileage 
    GROUP BY Reg_no
) MG ON  V.Reg_no=MG.Reg_no
INNER JOIN Mileage M ON MG.MaxID=M.MID
```

Should work on MySQL versions